# CSS Triangle under <td> element in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to add CSS triangle under table `<td>` element, to make something like 
[image: arrow under td]
how can I put that triangle like floating above the second `tr` and not changing the `td` height, example for my problem:

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
.arrow-down {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      (1)
    </td>
    <td>
      (2)<br><br>
    </td>
    <td>
      (3)
      <div class="arrow-down">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      (4)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      bla bla
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the pseudo element `::after` in the `td`

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  position:relative
}
tr:first-of-type td:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 15px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      (1)
    </td>
    <td>
      (2)
      <br /><br />
    </td>
    <td>
      (3)
    </td>
    <td>
      (4)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      bla bla
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: AFAIK yes it is ;)

Comment: Any suggestions how to deal with longer text on other td? because of absolute position, your solution will not show after the td like the picture if there's another td with larger height

Comment: can't reproduce what you mean, are you able to make a fiddle so I can help you?

Comment: @barha see updated answer, I used `bottom`instead of `top`, now you can have the `height` and `width` as much as you want